# Is there a FluxCD equivalent to "argocd app wait" or "helm upgrade --wait"?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, flux, fluxcd

I did the following to deploy a helm chart (you can copy-and-paste my sequence of commands to reproduce this error).

```
$ flux --version
flux version 0.16.1

$ kubectl create ns traefik

$ flux create source helm traefik --url https://helm.traefik.io/traefik --namespace traefik

$ cat values-6666.yaml
ports:
  traefik:
    healthchecksPort: 6666   # !!! Deliberately wrong port number!!!

$ flux create helmrelease my-traefik --chart traefik --source HelmRepository/traefik --chart-version 9.18.2 --namespace traefik --values=./values-6666.yaml
✚ generating HelmRelease
► applying HelmRelease
✔ HelmRelease created
◎ waiting for HelmRelease reconciliation
✔ HelmRelease my-traefik is ready
✔ applied revision 9.18.2
```

So Flux reports it as a success, and can be confirmed like this:

```
$ flux get helmrelease --namespace traefik
NAME        READY   MESSAGE                             REVISION    SUSPENDED
my-traefik  True    Release reconciliation succeeded    9.18.2      False
```

But in fact, as shown above, `values-6666.yaml` contains a deliberately wrong port number 6666 for pod's readiness probe (as well as liveness probe):

```
$ kubectl -n traefik describe pod my-traefik-8488cc49b8-qf5zz
  ...
  Type     Reason    ... From     Message
  ----     ------    ... ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy ... kubelet  Liveness  probe failed: Get "http://172.31.61.133:6666/ping": dial tcp 172.31.61.133:6666: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy ... kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://172.31.61.133:6666/ping": dial tcp 172.31.61.133:6666: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff   ... kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

My goal is to have FluxCD automatically detect the above error. But, as shown above, FluxCD deems it a success.

Either of the following deployment methods would have detected that failure:

```
$ helm upgrade --wait ...
```

or

```
$ argocd app sync ... && argocd app wait ...
```

So, is there something similar in FluxCD to achieve the same effect?

====================================================================

P.S. [Flux docs here](https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/helm/helmreleases/#disabling-resource-waiting) seems to suggest that the equivalent to `helm --wait` is already the default behaviour in FluxCD. My test above shows that it isn't. Furthermore, in the following example, I explicitly set it to `disableWait: false` but the result is the same.

```
$ cat helmrelease.yaml
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: my-traefik
  namespace: traefik
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: traefik
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: traefik
      version: 9.18.2
  install:
    disableWait: false      # !!! Explicitly set this flag !!!
  interval: 1m0s
  values:
    ports:
      traefik:
        healthchecksPort: 6666

$ kubectl -n traefik create -f helmrelease.yaml
helmrelease.helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/my-traefik created

  ## Again, Flux deems it a success:
$ flux get hr -n traefik
NAME        READY   MESSAGE                             REVISION    SUSPENDED
my-traefik  True    Release reconciliation succeeded    9.18.2      False

  ## Again, the pod actually failed:
$ kubectl -n traefik describe pod my-traefik-8488cc49b8-bmxnv
... // Same error as earlier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm considers a deployment with one replica and strategy rollingUpdate with maxUnavailable of 1 to be ready when it has been deployed and there is 1 unavailable pod. If you test Helm itself, I believe you will find the same behavior exists in the Helm CLI / Helm SDK package upstream.

(Even if the deployment's one and only pod has entered CrashLoopBackOff and readiness and liveness checks have all failed... with maxUnavailable of 1 and replicas of 1, the deployment technically has no more than the allowed number of unavailable pods, so it is considered ready.)

This question was re-raised recently at: https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-controller/issues/355 and I provided more in-depth feedback there.

Anyway, as for the source of this behavior which is seemingly/clearly not what the user wanted (even if it appears to be specifically what the user has asked for, which is perhaps debatable):

As for Helm, this appears to be the same issue reported at GitHub here:

- [helm install --wait does not wait for deployment pod readiness properly - (helm/helm#3173)](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3173)
  and resurrected here:
- [helm upgrade --wait does not wait on newer versions - (helm/helm#10061)](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/10061)

Answer (score 0):

FluxCD v2 is by default using the `--wait` option of Helm.
In general, you can use any Helm parameter of the CLI in the HelmRelease object:
https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/helm/helmreleases/

I recommend to invest in proper readiness probes of your pods. Helm/FluxCDv2 will wait for all pods to become ready. Liveness probes have a different purpose. Kubelet uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container. Usually they are not of interest for Helm/Flux.

If you have a complex application lifecycle, then take a look into [Kubernetes Operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDrmD.png) - (C) Jason Dobies, Joshua Wood. With the help of kstatus and kustomize you can let flux wait for your custom ressource to become ready.

Comment: It's the same thing with readiness probe which I didn't show in my original post. Now I've amended my original post to show the complete sequence of commands (which you can copy-and-paste to reproduce the error) as well as the failure of the readiness probe.